# $_SESSION variable not saving

Tags: php, session, submit

**Edit: Made a simplified script.**

I can't manage to save $_SESSION['test_var'] on the page below.
When I set the second submit I get no echo.

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
                $_SESSION['test_var'] = 1;
                echo "test_var set!";
            }
            if(isset($_POST['submit2'])){
                if(isset($_SESSION['test_var'])){
                    echo "test_var still set!";
                }
            }
        ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form NAME="testform" METHOD="POST" ACTION="test_session.php">
            <INPUT TYPE="Submit" NAME="submit1" VALUE="Set"><br>
        </form>
        <form NAME="testform2" METHOD="POST" ACTION="test_session.php">
            <INPUT TYPE="Submit" NAME="submit2" VALUE="Test"><br>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you show us how you are trying to save `$_SESSION['login']` on the other page?

Comment: also, do you have error reporting turned on?  If so, any errors?

Comment: I've added the code for page 1 (submitContent.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved!**
The problem was I had to save the file in **ANSI**, it was saved in **UTF-8**

Answer (score 0):

You do realize that you are echoing it out into the `<head>` of the document. To see if it is there try viewing the page source. Right click on chrome and do view page source. I think that is the problem.
Also be sure you are posting to the SAME subdomain. That means if you are on `domain.com` and you post to `www.domain.com` the session will not be the same.

Comment: When the first submit is made I can see the 'test_var set!' echo, so thats not the problem. On both forms ACTION="test_session.php".

Comment: I ran your exact code and it worked perfectly fine for me.. It could be your settings or something :\ I put it online here if you want to look. http://tronner.com/tools/SO/test_session.php